# How to retain Textbox's State after Postback in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on a form which is having a gridview & save button.Gridview has a checkbox & a textbox.If i clicked on checkbox and if it is checked,the textbox in that row becomes disable and if it is unchecked,the textbox in that row becomes enable.For this purpose i'm using following JQuery code & it is working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    try {
        $("input[type=checkbox][id*=chkChild]").click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=txtRemark]").attr("disabled", true);
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=txtRemark]").val("NA");
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=txtRemark]").focus();
            } else {

                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=txtRemark]").attr("disabled", false);
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=txtRemark]").val("");
                $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=txtRemark]").focus();
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

But after postback if i the textbox is disabled then it is not retaining its disable state & it becomes enable.
So please tell me how to maintain its state.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two options:
1) Call your Jquery function after each page postback, but making a loop in each line of the gridview and read the checkbox (checked or not). It would be call the function you did but for each grid line.
 
2) Doing this function in the server side code. But I believe that is not your intention.